# Bootstrap fields on same line

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-steps

Does anyone know why my "termination Date" field is not going on the same line as Date Hired? When I am following the same rules as all the fields above?

```
<h1>Employee</h1>
<fieldset>
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input id="todaysDate" name="todaysDate" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Job Title</label>
                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Department</label>
                <input id="department" name="department" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date Hired</label>
                <input id="hiredDate" name="hiredDate" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Termination Date</label>
                <input id="termDate" name="termDate" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're structure is wrong, in order to accomplish what you want your code should be:

```
<h1>Employee</h1>
<fieldset>
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input id="todaysDate" name="todaysDate" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date Hired</label>
                <input id="hiredDate" name="hiredDate" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Job Title</label>
                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Department</label>
                <input id="department" name="department" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Termination Date</label>
                <input id="termDate" name="termDate" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

in this way you have **1 row with 2 columns (3 inputs per column)**, so when collapsed the first column elements will be displayed before the second column ones (so **left elements before right ones**).

But if when collapsed you need to show the **top elements before the bottom ones**, you may want to do something like:

```
<h1>Employee</h1>
<fieldset>
    <h2>Employee Information</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input id="name" name="name" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Job Title</label>
                <input id="title" name="title" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date</label>
                <input id="todaysDate" name="todaysDate" type="text" class="form-control required">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Department</label>
                <input id="department" name="department" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Date Hired</label>
                <input id="hiredDate" name="hiredDate" type="text" class="form-control required email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Termination Date</label>
                <input id="termDate" name="termDate" type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</fieldset>
```

And you will have **3 rows with 2 columns each (1 input per column)**.

Comment: @DavidBrierton I've just edited my answer, now you have 2 alternatives:  1 row having 2 columns (with 3 inputs per column), or 3 rows having 2 columns (with 1 input per column).